# Two Ampersands Between Function Calls

Tags: php

What do two ampersands separating function calls do? Note: this is OUTSIDE any if statement or case statement

Like so:

```
functionCallOne() && functionCallTwo();
```

Comment: It may be an effective space-saving measure, but IMO it has a detrimental effect on clarity.  The untutored observer might easily assume that a big bold AND operator would call function1 AND function2.  Not function1, and then maybe function2, on a good day.  Programmers do love being too clever for their own good, of course!

Comment: @thesunneversets, this is more common than you think and is used in other languages like shell scripting.

Comment: I'm sure there are good and valid uses of it.  The most popular (and accepted) answer to this question describes its purpose solely as "to only take up one line".  Shorter code for its own sake is not always better code.

Comment: @thesunneversets +1, i usually prefer the 1-line if statement : `if(functionCallOne()) functionCallTwo();` same line count, greater clarity

Answer (score 7, accepted):

it is equivalent to

```
if ( functionCallOne() ) {
  functionCallTwo();
}
```

it just uses the short circuiting to make this 3 liner only take up one line

Answer (score 5):

That is the short-circuit AND operator, meaning the second function (or expression/statement) will only be evaluated if the first returns true.

Answer (score 1):

The logical AND operator `&&` is a short-circuit operator. That means it will only move on to examine the second operand if the first operand is `true`. If the first operand is `false`, the whole expression can only be `false`, so there's no point in checking the second operand, so it *short-circuits* out of the operation without having checked the second operand.

In this case this characteristic is used to mean "execute `functionCallOne` and if that was successful execute `functionCallTwo`".

Answer (score 0):

The second function (with all it's side-effects) is not even executed if the first one returns `false`, because PHP knows the whole expression can never be `true` if one of them is `false`.

Comment: What do you mean "with all it's side-effects"?

Comment: It is only useful to write `function_a() && function_b();` if function_b() has any side-effects other that returning a value.