# Is it more performant to use logical operators (Short circuiting AND) over conditional statements?

Tags: function, if-statement, conditional-statements, logical-operators

I have seen the use of logical operators in place of conditional statements used in some code I am currently reviewing, I am interested to know if using logical operators instead of conditional statements are more performant. Apart from the white-space and extra characters is there any advantage to doing this? (Clarity, maybe)

```
/* -- Using Logical Operator -- */
func1() && func2();

/* -- Using Conditional Statement -- */
if(func1()) {
  func2();
}
/* OR */
if(func1()) func2();
```

[Two Ampersands Between Function Calls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4139947/two-ampersands-between-function-calls) *(The question that sparked this)*

Comment: Did you read the accepted answer to the post you linked? It clearly says they are functionally the same, and the only reason to use the first rather than the second is to save two (irrelevant) line breaks. O (The third clearly doesn't save those line feeds either. Of course, you could always put a little effort into writing a benchmark to test it yourself...

Comment: Sorry, I will look into how to bench mark this sort of stuff since I am interested to know if there are any performance advantages rather than space saved.